# Which hypothesis test to use

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Two identical machines are used to make a special coin. We want to know if they have the same variability. A random sample is taken from each machine :

$$ \begin{matrix}
  MachineA & 135 & 138 & 136 & 140 & 138 & 135 & 139 \\
  MachineB & 140 & 135 & 140 & 138 & 135 & 138 & 140 \\
\end{matrix} $$

I have to give the test to use and do it with $\alpha=0.05$

**Edit:**

I ended up using F-test.
First machine variance is $3.9$
Second machine variance is $5$

$F = 5 / 3.9$

Critical value for df 6,6 with $\alpha = 0.05$ is $4.28$

Since the p-value is greater than $\alpha$ then the observed outcome was likely enough that it is reasonable to assume that the null hypothesis is true so fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Do you think the mean is a good measure for the variability in a machine?

Comment: Well Stefan, I guess Not, haha. I did further search and found that the F-test would be appropriate. Am I on the right track now ?

Comment: Assuming the two samples are two independent normally distributed samples (you need to validate this), then yes, an F-test for equal variances would be a way to go.